# A misunderstanding concerning $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The very well-known expression
$$\frac {\pi} {4} = 1 - \frac {1} {3} + \frac {1} {5} - \frac {1} {7} + \cdots$$
puts me face to face with a contradictory position. Let
$$s_N = \sum_{k = 0}^{N} \frac {1} {4k + 1} - \sum_{k = 0}^{N} \frac {1} {4k + 3}.$$
Then it is obvious that
$$\frac {\pi} {4} = \lim_{N \to \infty} s_N.$$
By Euler-MacLaurin summation formula,
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \frac {1} {4k + 1} = \int_{0}^{N} \frac {dx} {4x + 1} + \frac {1} {2} \left(1 + \frac {1} {4N + 1} \right) + o \left (\frac {1} {N^2} \right)$$
and
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \frac {1} {4k + 3} = \int_{0}^{N} \frac {dx} {4x + 3} + \frac {1} {2} \left(\frac {1} {3} + \frac {1} {4N + 3} \right) + o \left (\frac {1} {N^2} \right).$$
We then have
$$s_N = \frac {1} {4} \log \left(3 - \frac {6} {4N + 3} \right) + \frac {1} {3} + \frac {1} {(4N + 1) (4N + 3)} + o \left (\frac {1} {N^2} \right)$$
and
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} s_N = \frac {\log 3} {4} + \frac {1} {3}.$$
But $\frac {\log 3} {4} + \frac {1} {3} \ne \frac {\pi} {4}$. How come? Where have I done the mistake?

Comment: Your sum is only conditionally convergent. See the Riemann Series Theorem for more.

Comment: I do not understand... Can you please be more elaborate?

Comment: I think what people are reacting to is your "Indeed, write it as..." followed by a difference of two divergent series.

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh, I got it now. So, can't we cancel the terms like I did above?

Comment: See [conditionally convergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence).

Comment: On the next line, $s_N = \sum^N - \sum^N$, it's OK again, since then (as you said) it's really a partial sum. The comments about conditionally convergent series come from people who probably stopped reading after that blatantly incorrect first line. If you want people to really read the question (which is an interesting one), you should remove the incorrect part.

Comment: Your asymptotics are incorrect. There has to be an $R=O(1)$ in there somewhere. Indeed, $\dfrac\pi4\approx\dfrac{\ln3}4+\dfrac13.$

Comment: Indeed, according to your asymptotics, we should have $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^N\frac1{4k+1}-\int_0^N\frac{dx}{4x+1}=\dfrac12,$ when, in fact, the limit is $\dfrac{\gamma+\ln2+\dfrac\pi2}4.~$ Likewise, instead of $\dfrac16$ we should have $\dfrac{\gamma+\ln6-\dfrac\pi2}4.$

Comment: @HansLundmark I edited my question and removed the difference of series part.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks for pointing that out. How did you arrive at those numbers?

Comment: @NimaBavari I have to say, this is a superbly well formulated question

Comment: @MathFreak what question, brother?

Comment: @NimaBavari The main question of this post that you wrote in LATE$\chi$

Comment: @MathFreak Thank you for your nice words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

such mistakes are sometimes difficult to track down! however, your idea is an interesting one. it leads to the following expansion:
$$
S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac1{4k+1}-\frac1{4k+3} \\
=1 -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{4k-1}-\frac1{4k+1}
$$
hence
$$
1-S =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{4k-1}-\frac1{4k+1} \\
=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(4k)^2}\left(1-\frac1{(4k)^2}\right)^{-1} \\
=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(4k)^{2n}} \\
=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{4^{2n}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^{2n}} \\
=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2^{4n}}
$$
now, using the [expression for the zeta function at even integers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93879/riemann-zeta-at-even-integers) in terms of the Bernouilli numbers:
$$
2\zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}B_{2n}
$$
we obtain
$$
1-S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)^{2n}
$$
and, rearranging, with $S=\frac{\pi}4$, we obtain
$$
\frac{\pi}4 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{i\pi}2\right)^{2n}
$$

Answer (score 6):

The error surely lies in the $o\left({1\over N^2}\right)$ term(s).  Look at it this way:  Your use of Euler-Maclaurin would suggest

$$\sum_{k=1}^N{1\over k}=\int_1^N{dx\over x}+{1\over2}\left(1+{1\over N}\right)+o\left({1\over N^2}\right)$$

as well, which would suggest

$$\sum_{k=1}^N{1\over k}-\log N\to{1\over2}$$

instead of $\gamma\approx0.5772$.

Comment: And not in the misuse of conditionally convergent series, or in both?

Comment: The first line with the difference of the two infinite series is wrong. As @Hans Lundmark pointed out, however, the following one is correct (you didn't actually use the first), so the error lies after that (once you "remove" or ignore the first line). The asymptotic expansion is most likely the culprit -- this, and/or a computation error.

Comment: @NimaBavari: You have not misused anything. Your treatment of partial sums is completely rigorous.

Comment: I removed the first line.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by others, you misused the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Indeed, the next terms will involve some coefficients times powers of $1,\dfrac13,\dfrac1{4N+1}$ and $\dfrac1{4N+3}$. The constant terms do not vanish as $N\to\infty$.